# What is the fastest way to move simple text to table in org mode?

Tags: org-mode

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1.

Suppose I has the next text

```
OrganizationName    GUID

Advertisment    aaaaaaaa-14d7-4af5-ad10-ccccccc

Anelik  1c970d12-6c67-44e1-aa3f-bbbbbbbbb
```

I need to convert this text to table in **org mode**.
So result must be like this:

```
| OrganizationName | GUID                                 |    
|------------------+--------------------------------------|    
| Advertisment     | aaaaaaaa-14d7-4af5-ad10-ccccccc      |    
| Anelik           | 1c970d12-6c67-44e1-aa3f-bbbbbbbbb    |
```

So I wan't do this line by line. Maybe has faster approach?

Answer (score 6):

org-mode has `org-table-create-or-convert-from-region`, bound to <kbd>C-c |</kbd>. Just select the region you want to convert beforehand. You can use <kbd>C-c -</kbd> at the end of the first line to insert the dashes. [Org Tables](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Tables) explains this in great detail.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the multiple-cursors package to insert the `|` as needed. Just put a cursor at the beginning of each line, then it's just <kbd>C-n</kbd><kbd>C-S-Backspace</kbd><kbd>C-p</kbd> to remove the blank lines and return the cursors to the beginning of each row-line, then <kbd>|</kbd><kbd>M-e</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to insert the pipes at the beginning and after each first-word, escape multi-cursors mode, and get org-mode to format the table. After that, you just need to insert a blank line below the header, type `|-` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to insert that horizontal line.